# Многопоточность в PHP

Tags: php, многопоточность, curl

Здравствуйте. Необходимо реализовать кроссплатформенную многопоточность на PHP. Задача следующая, допустим, есть метод для каких либо вычислений, числа пи, число Фибоначчи и т.п., необходимо запустить этот метод в несколько потоков. Каким образом можно реализовать подобную задачу?
Нагуглил, что можно реализовать используя cURL, но не совсем понимаю логику данного метода.

Попробую конкретизировать задачу. Есть функция, которая высчитывает определенное значение. Задается стартовое значение (точность вычислений), которое указывает количество выполнений. Допустим, мы хотим произвести вычисления с точностью 300, это можно было бы разбить на 3 потока:

1. вычислял бы значение от 1 до 100
2. от 101 до 200
3. от 201 до 300

В конце достаточно сложить результаты выполнения этих потоков и вывести результат. Но каким образом их запустить синхронно, понятия не имею.

Comment: В PHP нет многопоточности, кроме экспериментального расширения, которое я бы пока не стал использовать. Используйте многопроцессорность и очереди.

Comment: Я бы схитрил, написал программу на C++, запустил бы ее на сервере как сервис, и обращался бы к ней из PHP. Быстро, кросс-платформенно, просто. Как вариант можно послать два асинхронных ajax запроса, а веб-сервер сам их распределит.

Comment: Это не для продакшина. Это тестовое задание. А что за экспериментальное расширение?

Comment: непонятно, зачем это нужно на PHP? если код выполняется на сервере, а на экран выводится лишь результат, то зачем многопоточность? Но в принципе несколько curl() запросов можно послать. Вот здесь можно почитать: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/php/examples/multi.html... Т.е. в Вашем примере посылаются 3 curl() запроса (вычисление 1 - 100, 101 - 200, 201 - 300). С каждого получается результат и выводится. Фактически, это многопоточность :)